# Regular expression name of series grouped in 3 groups

Tags: regex, expression

I'm starting learning regular expression and I stuck almost 3 days on the problem. I need regular expression which will group name of the series, season with  number of episode and everything else. I came up with this, but not the result I needed.

```
(.*)([Ss]?[0-9]{1,2}?[Ee]?[0-9]{1,2}?)(.*)
```

Code should work on these

```
Timeless.S01E05.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]
the.big.bang.theory.1007.hdtv-lol
dcs.legends.of.tomorrow.107.hdtv[ettv]
```

Comment: You should include the language you are using.  Not all regular expression parsers are the same.  Also, you need a better explanation of what "works" and "not works" means.  After all, `'^.*$'` "works" on the examples you give.

Comment: Python and it doesn't work when I use it :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more maintainable if you used one regex per year, season, etc?

Answer (score 0):

3 days well spent. Finaly figured it out. expression works with tv series startin with number or if the movie title has a year in it.

```
([0-9]{1,4}?.*?|.*[0-9]{4}.?|.*?)([Ss]?[0-9].+?[Ee]?[0-9]+?)([^0-9].+$)
```